# external page/control in jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm building an web application using Asp.Net, How I can load other page or control ( like login or feedback form) in dialog and make sure postback events of that control/page execute successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out various JQuery plugins, I finally choose popup extender of Asp.Net Ajax control toolkit.

The problem that I was facing with JQuery plugins, they do not handle postpack event properly. JQuery UI dialog is the closest match to my requirement, I will try it again next time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery WoWWindow](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/wowwindow/).